# Peewee adding columns on demand

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have an sqlite database which I use as a data storage file for an application I develop in python.

Now the development of new features requires me to define new fields in the database. Is there a way, with peewee, of loading a database file, which used the old table definition (without new field) without getting an `SQLError: no such column` error?

Like an automatic insertion of the new field with a default value in the database. This would make life a lot easier for having backwards compatibility with opening database files from previous versions.

Comment: Take a look at django south http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html it's become the standard way for django app. Easily reusable for other app (non django app). Or http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz on your new table + default value on the new columns.

Comment: That is a garbage comment he's using peewee ORM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a web-based tool called [sqlite-web](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlite-web) that will allow you to manage your database schema using a GUI.

If you want to add columns on the fly in your Python code, check out peewee's migration extension: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations

Comment: Yeah, I think the peewee migrate extension is the one I should use in this case.

Comment: That's awesome!